# scanner cannot read last int from a string

Tags: java, string, int, java.util.scanner

```
    if (diceValues == null || diceValues.length() == 0) return 0;
    int temp;
    int val = 0;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(diceValues);
    while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        temp = scanner.useDelimiter(" ").nextInt();
        if (temp == 1) val += 100;
        if (temp == 5) val += 50;
    }
```

diceValue is a string like this: "1 2 3 4 5", and the scanner always skips the last number. So the int val(value) always smaller than it should be.

Comment: Have you debugged this program correctly because I can see that all values are read from the scanner correctly

Comment: How do you know it's skipping the last number?  I just tried it with a `System.out.println(temp)`, and it displayed all 5 numbers.

Answer (score 1):

I think your code has no problem.I ran it this way and it returned me value 150.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Prog1 
{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Prog1 p =new Prog1();
        int value = p.mymethod();
        System.out.println(value);
    }
    public int mymethod()
    {
        String diceValues = "1 2 3 4 5";
        if (diceValues == null || diceValues.length() == 0) return 0;
        int temp;
        int val = 0;
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(diceValues);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
        temp = scanner.useDelimiter(" ").nextInt();
            if (temp == 1) val += 100;
            if (temp == 5) val += 50;
        }
        return val;
    }
```

Comment: thank you, I should look for other parts of my program then.